# Calling SP on mirrored server

Tags: sql-server

**Example: Procedure**

```
Select * from Server1.database1.Dbo.Table 1

inner join Server2.Database2.Dbo.Table 2

on 1.col1 = 2.col2
```

I'm calling this SP from another application having permissions on both server1 and server2
Both server1 and server2 are set up in mirroring. I'm having no issues with calling that SP if both databases reside on same server.
But if both reside on different servers then I'm getting error

> 'The database "database2/1" cannot be opened. It is acting as a mirror database.'

Can someone provide any solution for this.

Comment: You can try to use  `Select * from Server1.database1.Dbo.Table t1
    inner join Server2.Database2.Dbo.Table t2
    on t1.col1 = t2.col2` , becuase your alias name is illegal

Comment: Mirror databases are constantly in a RESTORING state - you should not be able to access anything in them unless you break the mirror and restore them or they become the principal due to a failover.

Comment: What is the underlying problem/issue/case that you are trying to solve?